# KEYCODE_ENTER - how to?

Tags: java, android

More of a query rather than a solid question. I have been using the code below within a search bar to listen for the enter key. Is it possible on some mobile devices, that with the different types of keyboards installed (factory, google etc) that various methods will not be listened to and work in the same manner?

I hope that makes sense.

```
private void init(){
    Log.d(TAG, "init: initialising");

    mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                    || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                //execute method for searching
                geoLocate();


            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```